# Force hyphenation or make newline in \tt

Tags: margins, hyphenation, typewriter, overflow

##### Overview

The goal is to get a tt rendering but with no right text overflow, in any case. I try to force LaTeX to make hyphenation or, if it’s not possible, newline. No matter if sometimes it let a gap in the right side.

##### MWE

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
\begin{quotation}
  \tt

  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

##### The rendering

And the corresponding rendering:

[image: Rendering]

##### Conclusion

As you see, the behaviour doesn’t really feat my expectations. Sometimes, LaTeX force an overflow.

##### The question

How to just tell LaTeX “Never, never, never overflow in the right side. You have only two choices: hyphenate or break line ?

Comment: The `\tt` command has been deprecated for almost 30 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}

% for the example
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
  \ttfamily\RaggedRight
  \kant[1-2]
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

I use `kantlipsum` which produces English sentences. Also `microtype` can do small adjustments.

[image]